# Using Redact in MongoDB to sort subdocuments on condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently fighting with the Aggregate framework in MongoDB to try to find the result I want. I've got a query that is pulling subdocuments correctly, I now however want to filter this based on a condition inside the subdocument and further sort this (which is why I can't use Find())

I currently have this as my query, however the $if statement isn't working

```
    const regions = await Region.aggregate(
    { $match: { name: res.locals.currentUser.region } },
    { $lookup: { from: 'products', localField: 'products', foreignField: '_id', as: 'returned_product' } },
            {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": {
                 $eq: ["$category", "motors"] },
                "then": "$$DESCEND",
                "else": "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }
    },

    { $sort: { 'product.urn': 1 } });
    res.json(regions);
```

Without Redact, I can successfully pull the subdocument based on my initial filter, this is returned in the following format:

```
[    
 {
"_id": "5a3010380a927941bf38ba87",
"__v": 0,
"name": "glasgow",
"products": [
  "5a2fb8582d8b90614150d53c",
  "5a2fb8a02d8b90614150d53d",
  "5a301d16d45fb65efd513e63",
  "5a30212c04078b6aa043bcc0"
],
"returned_product": [
  {
    "_id": "5a2fb8582d8b90614150d53c",
    "urn": "le00005",
    "category": "motors",
    "thumbnail": "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/creativestore/leisure/LE00001/ceebdbed17cc99d12d327275ac50e24e-thumb",
    "image": "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/creativestore/leisure/LE00001/ceebdbed17cc99d12d327275ac50e24e-full",
    "printProof": "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/1513076823969LE00001.pdf",
    "digitalProof": "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/1513076823978MO00002ASAS.pdf",
    "__v": 0,
    "tags": [
      "business"
    ],
    "mockups": [
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/creativestore/leisure/LE00001/d7a4a45b00a76648e0778f571746cc21-full",
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/creativestore/leisure/LE00001/c7e029d91eb63ba1092e092d0a9b897c-full",
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/creativestore/leisure/LE00001/cae3859f497fc4b9b63425d6b7324bd4-full",
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/creativestore/leisure/LE00001/de53bd7dec272322ce7e517af5309736-full",
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/creativestore/leisure/LE00001/c5321e3e94e311d9eba6014991c40a83-full"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a301d16d45fb65efd513e63",
    "urn": "motors2",
    "category": "motors",
    "thumbnail": "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/creativestore/motors/motors2/5eec4730ad7f5a7c79cca286dc6ffb27-thumb",
    "image": "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/creativestore/motors/motors2/5eec4730ad7f5a7c79cca286dc6ffb27-full",
    "printProof": "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/1513102613401Digital File Template.pdf",
    "digitalProof": "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/1513102613408Digital File Template.pdf",
    "tags": [
      "motors"
    ],
    "mockups": [
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/creativestore/motors/motors2/e249adfba22d553af7f87fda48dcf29a-full",
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/creativestore/motors/motors2/67f572530cf1875f547b6bc88d8c259a-full"
    ],
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a30212c04078b6aa043bcc0",
    "urn": "sadsadf",
    "category": "leisure",
    "thumbnail": "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/creativestore/leisure/sadsadf/1ed6f624d7e99fc90440e77547555185-thumb",
    "image": "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/creativestore/leisure/sadsadf/1ed6f624d7e99fc90440e77547555185-full",
    "printProof": "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/1513103659119Digital File Template.pdf",
    "digitalProof": "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/1513103659127Digital File Template.pdf",
    "tags": [
      "leisure"
    ],
    "mockups": [
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/thecreativestore/creativestore/leisure/sadsadf/c9e6e465b38b7c2242171ab341ca46ec-full"
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

I've been banging my head off this (or some way to get the data categorised in this format) for days so even some pointers would be great!

Cheers,

Comment: Replace `$redact` with `$unwind` and `$match` to filter the returned product array followed by `$sort`. Something like `{
    "$unwind": "$returned_product"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "returned_product.category":"motors"
    }
  }`

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for your help! Just out of curiosity, what would a good use for $redact be?

Comment: You are welcome. `$redact` can be used to implement the access level filtering. More [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)